# ssh command doesn't terminate

Tags: linux, ssh, xorg, clipboard

I wrote a script to set my desktop clipboard from my Android phone.

```
#!/bin/sh

ssh -Y user@host "export DISPLAY=:0; echo -n $(termux-clipboard-get) | xclip -selection clipboard"
```

The script functions as expected but it doesn't terminate. I have to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to return to prompt.

I've used the `-f` option and it returns immediately. From `man ssh`:

> `-f`
> Requests `ssh` to go to background just before command execution.  This is useful if `ssh` is going to ask for passwords or passphrases, but the user wants it in the background. […]

I'm not sure if it's the right way to solve this. It doesn't need to run in the background. It just needs to execute a command and return.

Why doesn't my `ssh` return? Is `ssh -f` a good way? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316890/108618):

> Selections in X work by two X clients cooperating: One X client claims it has an selection (primary, secondary, clipboard), and another X client that wants to paste the selection contacts the first client to receive it.

In your case the original `xclip` dies but its child survives to claim it has the selection and to serve for future clients that want to paste. It appears it doesn't detach itself fully and the SSH server waits for it to exit; so your `ssh` client waits for it to exit. Hence the need for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Later, if another client claims it has the selection then the remote `xclip` will exit and unblock your local `ssh`. This means your workaround with `-f` is not so bad: background processes will not accumulate, there will be at most one stalled `ssh`.

The linked answer tries to solve a problem that seems somewhat related. [Another answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320487/108618) there advises `xsel`. Indeed, in my tests this doesn't block:

```
ssh -Y user@host "export DISPLAY=:0; echo -n foobar | xsel -i -b"
```

Changing `xclip` to `xsel` is crucial. Still your original command can be improved more.

- I think you don't need `-Y` (or `-X`) because the remote commands don't interact with your local X server. It's enough to set `DISPLAY` right to point `xsel` to the desired display that is *local* to `xsel`.
- No need to `export`. The variable is relevant only to `xsel`, so this snippet should be enough: `DISPLAY=:0 xsel -i -b`
- **Serious flaw.** `$(termux-clipboard-get)` is expanded locally and whatever you get from `termux-clipboard-get` will be embedded into the string you pass to the remote shell to be *iterpreted* as code.

  E.g. if `termux-clipboard-get` returns `; rm -f /very/important/file; true` then the remote shell will run

  ```
  export DISPLAY=:0; echo -n ; rm -f /very/important/file; true | …
  ```

  Do you see what it does? The right thing to do is to pipe to `ssh`:

  ```
  termux-clipboard-get | ssh user@host 'DISPLAY=:0 xsel -i -b'
  ```

  This way the output from `termux-clipboard-get` will not be treated as code, ever.
- I guess you deliberately used `echo -n` to get the output of `termux-clipboard-get` without any trailing newline character. If so, you should remove trailing newlines locally and [not rely on `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/108618):

  ```
  printf '%s' "$(termux-clipboard-get)" | …
  ```

The final form can be:

```
printf '%s' "$(termux-clipboard-get)" | ssh user@host 'DISPLAY=:0 xsel -i -b'
```

Note the command will strip trailing newline characters even from data that should be interpreted as binary and not altered. NUL characters will also be problematic. If you need to pass some data verbatim, then just pipe from `termux-clipboard-get` directly:

```
termux-clipboard-get | ssh …
```